# Win32 Application getting pixels to change to full blue,red or green color

Tags: c++, file, winapi, image-processing, bitmap

Hello all C++ Experts,

It's me again. I will get straight to the point.

I've successfully got the bitmap image rgb colors pixel which is (blue - 178, green - 130 and red 131).

What I do want to do next is to loop through the pixels and make it such that the picture will be totally blue. (Eg. Blue - 255, green - 0, red - 0)

I did tried a couple of for loops but it does not work, therefore, requiring assistance!

```
/*for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) 
{ 
image[i].rgbtBlue; 
image[i].rgbtGreen; 
image[i].rgbtRed; 
}*/
```

But obviously it does not work, that was why i needed the assistance. To add it on, hfile was being initialized for other purposes so i did not think it was relevant. Appreciated all the comments, thank you.

Thank you! As below is the code.

P.S: Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Win32 application, not Console.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "winmain.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <CommDlg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <WinGDI.h>

HANDLE hfile2; 
DWORD written; 
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh; 
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih; 
RGBTRIPLE *image;

hfile2 = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile`, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
//Read the header
ReadFile(hfile, &bfh, sizeof(bfh), &written, NULL);
ReadFile(hfile, &bih, sizeof(bih), &written, NULL);

// Read image
int imagesize = bih.biWidth * bih.biHeight; // Helps you allocate memory for the image
image = new RGBTRIPLE[imagesize]; // Create a new image (I'm creating an array during runtime
ReadFile(hfile, image, imagesize * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), &written, NULL); // Reads it off the disk
get_pixel(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight);
int test = bih.biHeight * bih.biWidth * bih.biBitCount;

RGBTRIPLE get_pixel(int x,int y)
{
    // Image define from earlier
    return image[(bih.biHeight-1-y)*bih.biWidth+x];
}
```

Comment: Please put spaces between arguments to functions and binary operators such as `*`. It makes everything way easier to read.

Comment: where are the type declarations for bfh, bih, hfile, etc? You initialize hfile2 but not hfile? Where is the code you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Editted the code and added in my comments, appreciated!

Comment: Please edit and update your question, don't put code in comments. Also, make sure all relevant function definitions are present, for example, what is get_pixel?

Comment: Have changed and update my question, thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the get_pixel() call if you do not store the result?

Comment: Hi shawn, i do understand i need to set_pixel, i have a set_pixel function too, it goes with (int x, int y and color), trying to figure out how to set it, after that what should i do? set the pixel with the image itself? I believe that is the way to do it but yet i've no idea how. Thanks!

Comment: What is RGBTRIPLE? A struct/class of 3 numbers?

Comment: @ksming: [`RGBTRIPLE` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162939.aspx) - standard Win32 type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment is pretty much right on. Each element `image[i]` *is* a `RGBTRIPLE` variable, which you can read and write. Therefore, `setpixel` is straightforward:

```
void set_pixel(int x,int y, RGBTRIPLE color)
{
    image[(bih.biHeight-1-y)*bih.biWidth+x] = color;
}
```

You see that the same code is used to select the right pixel of the image. You'll probably want to define a `const RGBTRIPLE blue;` constant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the file is `.BMP`. Apart from pixel data it also has headers you need to read, and also note that pixel lines are padded to 32-bti boundary. You need to take this all into consideration. Look for sample code/snippets online, e.g.:

- [Reading a BMP file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0af89fee-889b-49c8-8e64-94637c91869b)
- [Read and Write BMP in windows application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/c6f7ada9-7382-4f18-a563-10de5150e680)